# Mailchimp - how to tell when a user's status is set to pending

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'd like to be able to tell in my webhook when a user's status is set to `pending`. Setting a user's status to `pending` triggers a Profile Update event, but as far as I can see there is nothing in the form values posted to my webhook about the user's status for this event.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a feature request for MailChimp. Absent that, you can always query the user's info from the API to get their current status.

Comment: How do I make a feature request? Because setting a user's status to `pending` triggers a Profile Update event, I would have thought the status would be sent. There's no point querying the user's info from the API to check the status every time a Profile Update event occurs, because the status may not have changed.

Comment: I'd just pass along your usecase to customer support. I'm not aware of any other way to make such a request.